# Chinese Remainder Theorem, Miller-Rabin Primality test, and more...

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, primality-test, congruence-relations

Good day, I was going over the proof of the Miller-Rabin Primality Test and have a few questions regarding it. THE BOOK IS COMPLEXITY AND CRYPTOGRAPHY: AN INTRODUCTION

[image]

Where

> $B_t = \{a\in\Bbb Z_n^* |a^{m·2^t} = \pm1\bmod n \}$

and

> $t=\max [0≤i≤k−1|\exists a \in \Bbb Z_n^*\  \text{such that } \ a^{m·2^i} =−1\bmod n ]$

**My first question** concerns the last few lines. "The definition of t implies that...".

> If we say that $n=cd$, how do we show that $b^{m·2^t} \neq \pm1 \bmod n$ using the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

**My second question**

> If $a$ is coprime to n and
>
> $b = a \bmod c$ **and** $b = 1 \bmod d$
>
> Then how do we show that b is coprime to n?

**$n> d,c \geq 3$**

Comment: Answer to the second question : We have $n=cd$. Suppose there is a prime $p$ with $p|b$ and $p|n$. We can conclude $p|c$ or $p|d$ but because of $d|b-1$ , $p|d$ cannot hold because $p|d|b-1$ implies $p|b-1$ contradicting $p|b$. Hence, we can conclude $p|c$ and because of $c|b-a$ we finally have $p|a$ and arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: For your first question it would be better if you included the definition of $ t $ which is essential,  and any other relevant material to make the question self-contained.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier , I did, in fact, define $t$ and $B_t$. I highlighted them so they can stand out now.

Comment: @ʎpoqou My bad, I hadn't seen it. I don't understand your question then, why exactly do you need to show that $b^{m\cdot 2^t}\neq \pm1\bmod n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Since $a^{m.2^t} \equiv -1 \bmod n$ this gives $a^{m.2^t} \equiv -1 \bmod c$ and thus $b^{m.2^t} \equiv -1 \bmod c$. Obviously $b^{m.2^t} \equiv 1 \bmod d$. However this pair of results is not consistent with $b^{m.2^t} \in\{-1,1\} \bmod n$ and thus $b\not \in B_t$.

2) Since $a$ is coprime to $n$, it is also coprime to $c$ and thus $b$ is coprime to both $c$ and $d$.